# Int.Parse(String.Split()) returns "Input string was not in a correct format" error

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to perform a LINQ query on an array to filter out results based on a user's query. I am having a problem parsing two `int`'s from a single string.

In my database, TimeLevels are stored as strings in the format `[mintime]-[maxtime] minutes` for example `0-5 Minutes`. My user's have a slider which they can select a min and max time range, and this is stored as an `int` array, with two values. I'm trying to compare the `[mintime]` with the first value, and the `[maxtime]` with the second, to find database entries which fit the user's time range.

Here is my C# code from the controller which is supposed to perform that filtering:

```
RefinedResults = InitialResults.Where(
                x => int.Parse(x.TimeLevel.Split('-')[0]) >= data.TimeRange[0] &&
                int.Parse(x.TimeLevel.Split('-')[1]) <= data.TimeRange[1] &&).ToArray();
```

My thinking was that it would firstly split the `0-5 Minutes` string at the `-` resulting in two strings, `0` and `5 Minutes`, then parse the ints from those, resulting in just `0` and `5`.

But as soon as it gets to Int.Parse, it throws the error in the title.

Comment: is it Linq to Entity?

Comment: Split by space _as well_ in the latter int.Parse() expression

Comment: Better yet, test the formula without linq and you will find the error by yourself

Comment: Why do you store three informations in one column in the database?

Comment: What is the value of `x.TimeLevel.Split('-')[0]` exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül Well x.TimeLevel is (for example) `10-15 Minutes` so I was thinking that `x.TimeLevel.Split('-')[0]` would be `10`

Comment: Yes, `x.TimeLevel.Split('-')[0]` would be `10`. But `x.TimeLevel.Split('-')[1]` would be `15 Minutes`, not just `15`. `int.Parse(...)` will complain about the ` Minutes` part.

Comment: Do you get the same result with `TryParse` instead of `Parse`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well that's a bit of a problem. I followed @GrawCube's solution and that has fixed it, but some of the `x.TimeLevel` database records are stored as `30-40+ Minutes`. Is there any method just to extract the int?

Comment: @Frayt: it also doesn't seem to be the real code because of the `&&` at the end.

Comment: @Frayt You would probably find an easy solution with Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some of the `x.TimeLevel` database records are stored as `"30-40+ Minutes"`. Is there any method just to extract the `int`?

You could use regular expressions to match the integer parts of the string for you, like this:

```
RefinedResults = InitialResults
    .Where(x => {
        var m = Regex.Match(x, @"^(\d+)-(\d+)");
        return m.Success
            && int.Parse(m.Groups[1]) >= data.TimeRange[0]
            && int.Parse(m.Groups[2]) <= data.TimeRange[1];
    }).ToArray();
```

This approach requires the string to start in a pair of dash-separated decimal numbers. It would ignore anything after the second number, ensuring that only sequences of digits are passed to `int.Parse`.

Comment: How would I integrate this into a LINQ query with more than just the lines in my example?

Comment: Note that there is no need for square brackets around the hyphen. Also, it's `Groups`, not `Group` for the group collection property on the `Match` object. Other elements of the code example, such as the `^` in the expression and the validation of the `Success` variable may or may not be needed, depending on the OP's actual need (which is not very clear in his question).

Comment: @Frayt You can put additional conditions on the `return` line, or continue with other `Where` clauses, it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because string.Split("-", "0-5 Minutes") will return [0] = "0" and [1] = "5 Minutes", and the latter is not parseable as an int.

You can use the regular expression "\d+" to split up groups of digits and ignore non-digits. This should work:

```
var refinedResults = 
(
    from result in InitialResults
    let numbers = Regex.Matches(result.TimeLevel, @"\d+")
    where ((int.Parse(numbers[0].Value) >= data.TimeRange[0]) && (int.Parse(numbers[1].Value) <= data.TimeRange[1]))
    select result
).ToArray();
```

Here's a complete compilable console app which demonstrates it working. I've used dummy classes to represent your actual classes.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class SampleTime
    {
        public SampleTime(string timeLevel)
        {
            TimeLevel = timeLevel;
        }

        public readonly string TimeLevel;
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int[] TimeRange = new int[2];
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var initialResults = new []
            {
                new SampleTime("0-5 Minutes"),
                new SampleTime("4-5 Minutes"), // Should be selected below.
                new SampleTime("1-8 Minutes"),
                new SampleTime("4-6 Minutes"), // Should be selected below.
                new SampleTime("4-7 Minutes"),
                new SampleTime("5-6 Minutes"), // Should be selected below.
                new SampleTime("20-30 Minutes")
            };

            // Find all ranges between 4 and 6 inclusive.

            Data data = new Data();
            data.TimeRange[0] = 4;
            data.TimeRange[1] = 6;

            // The output of this should be (as commented in the array initialisation above):
            //
            // 4-5 Minutes
            // 4-6 Minutes
            // 5-6 Minutes

            // Here's the significant code:

            var refinedResults = 
            (
                from result in initialResults
                let numbers = Regex.Matches(result.TimeLevel, @"\d+")
                where ((int.Parse(numbers[0].Value) >= data.TimeRange[0]) && (int.Parse(numbers[1].Value) <= data.TimeRange[1]))
                select result
            ).ToArray();

            foreach (var result in refinedResults)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.TimeLevel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are splitting by `-` and not also by space which is  the separator of the `minutes` part. So you could use `Split(' ', '-')` instead:

```
InitialResults
    .Where(x => int.Parse(x.TimeLevel.Split('-')[0]) >= data.TimeRange[0] 
             && int.Parse(x.TimeLevel.Split(' ','-')[1]) <= data.TimeRange[1])
    .ToArray();
```

As an aside, don't  store three informations in one column in the database. That's just a source of nasty errors and bad performance. It's also more difficult to filter in the database which should be the preferred way or to maintain datatabase consistency.

---

Regarding your comment that the format can be `0-40+ Minutes`. Then you could use...

```
InitialResults
    .Select(x => new { 
        TimeLevel = x.TimeLevel, 
        MinMaxPart = x.TimeLevel.Split(' ')[0]
    })
    .Select(x => new { 
        TimeLevel = x.TimeLevel, 
        Min = int.Parse(x.MinMaxPart.Split('-')[0].Trim('+')),
        Max = int.Parse(x.MinMaxPart.Split('-')[1].Trim('+'))
    })
    .Where(x => x.Min >= data.TimeRange[0] && x.Max <= data.TimeRange[1])
    .Select(x => x.TimeLevel)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that does in fact work. However I made a comment on the OP that some of the x.TimeLevel database records are stored as 30-40+ Minutes. I could also split by `+` but I think that would cause errors for records without the `+`

Comment: @Frayt: have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Error happens because of the " Minutes" part of the string.
You can truncate the " Minutes" part before splitting, like;
x.TimeLevel.Remove(x.IndexOf(" "))
then you can split.